# Can we set background image to svg <path> and set background-attachment to fixed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

**Can we set background image to svg  and set background-attachment to fixed ?**
Like this is a (cat) svg file URL https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Cat_black.svg

If i write this in an html file, I want to add background-image on that svg structure and want to set background-attachment fixed.

Comment: If your using the `<path>` of a svg, I don't think you can put it as a background. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Hi @CarlJan, Thanks for your response.
Well i searched on it we can make a pattern tag and set it as background of path by giving fill:('#id_of_pattern'), But i want to make it as background-attachment fixed.

Comment: Really? Well I guess I'm wrong haha

Comment: Please add an [mcve] showing what you have and explain more clearly what you want to happen instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson Please check updated question, Please explain if it is possible, Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, I did this before, if i write that svg tag in html, its not possible to give background-image to svg tag, But possible to give by adding a <pattren> tag and setting it to path, But i want to give background-attachment:fixed, How can i give fixed background image to svg structure

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I have no imagination whatsoever so just a text description ain't gonna cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Judging the circumstances it looks like you want to know how to set background-image, you can do so like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body{
      background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Cat_black.svg');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
      background-size:200px auto;
      background-attachment:fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```